# String Check not returning a value

Tags: c, string, substring

Program should read in any input a user desires (in this case just a string of a’s and b’s) ended by an “*”, then it prompts the user for the substring they wish to search for (in this case “baab”). If the substring is found then the program indicates a yes, no if its not found.  I was not allowed to use built in matching utilities and it has to read one character at a time.

I just replaced gets() with a scanf, now when i type in my substring and im sure its a match it still says no?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int search(char[], char[]);

int main()
{
    char a[100], b[40];
    int loc;

    printf("Enter the main string :");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("Enter the search string :");
    scanf("%s", b);

    loc = search(a, b);

    if (loc == -1)
        printf("No");
    else
        printf("Yes %d", loc + 1);

    return (0);
}

int search(char a[], char b[])
{
    int i, j, firstOcc;

    i = 0, j = 0;

    while (a[i] != '*')
    {
        while (a[i] != b[0] && a[i] != '*')
            i++;
        if (a[i] == '*')
            return (-1);

        firstOcc = i;

        while (a[i] == b[j] && a[i] != '*' && b[j] != '*')
        {
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        if (b[j] == '*')
            return (firstOcc);
        if (a[i] == '*')
            return (-1);

        i = firstOcc + 1;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a `\n` at the end of your `printf` strings (*e.g.*, `printf("No\n");`). Then you'll see the output. You are probably getting "No" but it's occurring with your prompt. Look carefully. :)

Comment: PLEASE don't use `gets`. It is very dangerous. You will get buffer overflow. `fgets` is somewhat safer (you can specify the max number of bytes read), `getline` is even better (it will adjust the input buffer to match the characters read). `gets` should have been taken out of the language a long time ago.

Comment: I actually got a warning about gets() when I compiled.  You should compile with the -W tag and fix all warnings.  They are there for a reason.

Comment: Wow. I just compiled your code. When I ran it, the output was `"warning: this program uses gets, which is unsafe"`. Before it gave the actual prompt "Enter the main string". Not kidding. `gcc` on the Mac... I had never seen that warning - because I have not used `gets` in years. Note - the warning happened when I RAN the code... not when I compiled.

Comment: The problem is that you are not putting an asterisk at the end of the `b` string, is my guess...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on the gets() i changed it to scanf and used the info on the below post and it seemingly works

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate the second string with a `*` as well - then things match properly. As it is, your code keeps matching "one character too much" - and it finds the '\0' at the end of the `b` string which doesn't match.

If you don't want to have an asterisk at the end of your b string, you must not write code that expects it... You could modify your code as follows (I put in ample `printf` statements so you can see what is going on). Note - I left the fix to `gets` in as an exercise. Really, please. Fix it.

```
include <stdio.h>

int search(char a[], char b[]);

int main()
{
    char a[100], b[40];
    int loc;

    printf("Enter the main string terminated with '*':");
    gets(a); // please don't...

    printf("Enter the search string :");
    gets(b);

    loc = search(a, b);

    if (loc == -1)
        printf("No");
    else
        printf("Yes %d", loc + 1);

    return (0);
}

int search(char a[], char b[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, lenB, firstOcc;

    for(lenB=0; b[lenB]!='\0';lenB++);

    printf("a is %s\n", a);
    while (a[i] != '*')
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        while (a[i] != b[0] && a[i] != '*')
            i++;
        if (a[i] == '*')
            return (-1);
        printf("matching a[i]=%c and b[0]=%c\n", a[i], b[0]);

        firstOcc = i;

        while (a[i] == b[j] && a[i] != '*' && j < lenB)
        {
            printf("a[%d] matches b[%d]\n", i, j);
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        if (j == lenB)
            return (firstOcc);
        if (a[i] == '*')
            return (-1);

        i = firstOcc + 1;
        j = 0;
        printf("going to take another look with i=%d and j=%d\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works, you might consider accepting the answer (with the check mark next to the question).